# Marketing Cloud - Mobile Connect - Outbound SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

Can put AMPScript that redirects to another page in the SMS template as shown in the figure below?

[image]

I am try to do this because, I need to capture interactions and POST them to a web service.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I was not able to try this as I could not send out any SMS messages. Would be helpful to know if any of you have already tried or if it possible in the first place.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to build something in the platform, it's best to do whatever you need to do to test it.

First the AMPScript function is `redirectto()` not `redirect()`.

Regardless, I doubt it will work, since you'd be redirecting from the target users messaging app, not a SFMC email or page.

There's nothing stopping you from outputting a link in your message, but I don't think any automatic redirection in a SMS is a thing.

Comment: I need to capture the following SMS interactions and POST them a webservice.   When the user response is Y / when the session expires / when the user response is STOP. I need to capture these interactions and make a POST call to a webservice. I thought of having some SSJS on the redirect page and make these calls. If this is not possible, can you think of an alternative way to do this?